# How to add two different models in perform_create in REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models I would like to create together with only one request. Can this be done in one `perform_create` or is there a way around?

models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField() 

class Bar(models.Model):
   foo = models.ForeignKey('foo)
```

views:

```
class FooViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):

serializer_class = FooSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
     #???
```

I want `Bar` created every time `Foo` is created.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, it could be defined in the `FooSerializer` with a [writeable nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

However, if you always "want Bar created every time Foo is created", then I would do this by [catching the `Foo` Model's `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) and create the required `Bar`. That makes sure that Bar is created, even if you create a Foo in the shell, for example.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def create_bar_on_foo_created(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Bar.objects.get_or_create(foo=instance)
```